# r polygon fillOddEven parameter

Tags: r, data-visualization

How does the `fillOddEven` parameter work in the `polygon` function  in R? I have tried a couple of examples but can't spot a change:

```
layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=2))
x <- c(1:9, 8:1)
y <- c(1, 2*(5:3), 2, -1, 17, 9, 8, 2:9)
plot(1:10)
polygon(x, y, col = "orange", lty = 2, lwd = 2, border = "red",fillOddEven = T)
plot(1:10)
polygon(x, y, col = "orange", lty = 2, lwd = 2, border = "red",fillOddEven = F)
```